# Java precedence for multiple + and - operators

Tags: java, evaluation, arithmetic-expressions

This is more of a theoretical question to understand Java's evaluation of arithmetic operations. Since `+` and `-` have the same precedence, I don't quite understand how Java evaluates the following expressions (where there are more than one `+` and `-` operators between the two operands).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    System.out.println(a+-b);    // results in -1
    System.out.println(a-+b);    // results in -1
    System.out.println(a+-+b);   // results in -1
    System.out.println(a-+-b);   // results in  3
    System.out.println(a-+-+b);  // results in  3
    System.out.println(a+-+-b);  // results in  3
    System.out.println(a-+-+-b); // results in -1
    System.out.println(a+-+-+b); // results in  3
}
```

From the Java 8 Language Specification ([§15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)):

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>   The binary - operator performs subtraction, producing the difference of two numeric operands.
>   [...]
>   Addition is a commutative operation if the operand expressions have no side effects.
>   Integer addition is associative when the operands are all of the same type.

What I also noticed, is that everytime the #operators is even, the result is the same and the order doesn't matter.
But when the #operators is odd, this doesn't necessarily influence the result. E.g. in the following two expressions there is one more `-` than `+`, however the result is different.

```
System.out.println(a-+-b);   // results in 3
System.out.println(a-+-+-b); // results in -1
```

With all that information I still don't see the pattern or the way how this works.

Comment: i believe *a+-b* is executed as *a+ (-b)* . checking it out

Comment: @Sanket Makani `--` and `++` are not allowed in that case because Java takes it as increment/decrement operation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In math, how would you evaluate this?

```
a - + - b
```

Adding some brackets helps:

```
a - (+ (-b))
```

We can do this, because this doesn't violate the rules of precedence.

Then we can start reducing: `+ (-b)` is really `-b`, and `a - -b` is really `a + b`, so the result is `1 + 2 = 3`.

Let's see the second one:

```
a - + - + - b
a - (+ (- (+ (-b))))
a - (+ (- (-b)))
a - (+ b)
a - b
1 - 2 = -1
```

So simple rules of math work naturally.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the `-` sign negate expressions:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
System.out.println(a+(-b));
System.out.println(a+-b);
```

both print `-1`. This is from oracle docs:

> Unary minus operator; negates an expression

the minus simply **changes** the sign of the number after it. If `b` were negative, then `a+-b` would return `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Its evaluated as it is in how you do calculations in math with addition and subtraction.
In your example all your calculations start with the smaller number `a=1`, then you have `-`, and `+` signs between a small number and a bigger number b=2. for example when you do `1 -- 2`, you are doing `1+2` because 2 `-` signs cancel each other becomes `1 + 2`, `1 - 2` will  be -1 because 2 ( larger number has a - sign, which makes it a negative integer, adding a 1 to a negative integer increases its value by one

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a mathematical issue... (- & - = +), (- & + = -) and (+ & + = +)

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
System.out.println(a+-b);    // 1 +(-2) = 1-2 = -1
System.out.println(a-+b);    // 1-(+2) = 1-2 = -1
System.out.println(a+-+b);   // 1+-(+2) = 1-(+2) = 1-2 = 1
System.out.println(a-+-b);   // 1- + (-2) = 1- (-2) = 1+2 =3 
System.out.println(a-+-+b);  // 1 - + - (+2) = 1 - - (+2) = 1-2 = -1
System.out.println(a+-+-b);  // 1+ - + (-2) =1 - + (-2) = 1+2 = 3 
System.out.println(a-+-+-b); // 1-+-+(-2) = 1 - - (-2) = 1 + (-2) = -1
System.out.println(a+-+-+b); // 1 +- +- (+2) = 1 -- (+2) = 1+2 = 3
```